# Multiplication Table in Javascript space between numbers?

Tags: javascript

```
 var numbers = ""; 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++){
      for (var j = 1; j<= 13; j++){
          numbers += (i*j) + '';
       }
       numbers += '<br>';
    }

element.innerHTML = numbers;
```

how can i make a space between every number?

example:
[image]

Comment: Wrap the numbers in an appropriate element, and use CSS.

Comment: Consider using a table element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <[table](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)> for that to structure your text:

```js
let numbers = "<tbody>"; 
for (let i = 1; i <= 13; i++){
  numbers += '</tr>';
  for (let j = 1; j<= 13; j++){
      numbers += `<td>${i*j}</td>`;
  }
  numbers += '</tr>';
}
numbers += "</tbody>"
const element = document.querySelector("#element");
element.innerHTML = numbers;
```

```css
td {
  text-align: right;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table id="element">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be ambitious and, like David said, use CSS to take the weight of how the data is meant to be displayed. I've used [`CSS grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) in this example which means you only need to have one loop, and the CSS takes care of the rest.

```js
const arr = [];

const size = 13;
const limit = size * size;

// Push an HTML template string into
// the array
for (var i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
  arr.push(`<div>${i}</div>`);
}

// Add the joined array (it makes an HTML string
// to the element with the `grid` class
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
grid.innerHTML = arr.join('');
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 30px);
  grid-gap: 0.2em;
}

.grid div {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Edit: you can even create a function that will accept a number, and, using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), the function will work out the size of the grid required and return the HTML.

```js
function createGrid(columns) {

  const arr = [];
  const grid = columns * columns;

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--columns', columns)
  
  // Push an HTML template string into
  // the array
  for (var i = 1; i <= grid; i++) {
    arr.push(`<div>${i}</div>`);
  }

  return arr.join('');
}

const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
grid.innerHTML = createGrid(5);
```

```css
:root {
  --columns: 13;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 40px);
  grid-gap: 0.2em;
}

.grid div {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid` approach with some CSS variables to make cell elements, for more details see comments in Code snippet:

Also you could render headings of the cells.

```js
const gridSize = 13;

// get grid element
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

// create temporary wrapper
const fragmentWrapper = document.createDocumentFragment();

const renderTop = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i <= gridSize; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      // render mult char
      renderCell('x');
      
      continue;
    }
  
    renderCell(i, true);
  }
}

const renderGrid = () => {
  // append cells to wrapper
  for (var i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= gridSize; j++) {
      if (j === 0) {
        // render heading cell
        const num = i;
        renderCell(num, true);
        
        continue;
      }
      
      // render default cell
      const num = i * j;
      renderCell(num);
    }
  }
}

const renderCell = (num, select = false) => {
  // create temporary cell
  const cell = document.createElement('div');
  cell.className = 'cell';
  // if requested to highligh cell
  select && cell.classList.add('select');
  cell.innerText = `${ num }`;

  // add cell to grid 
  fragmentWrapper.append(cell);
}

renderTop();
renderGrid();

// set grid size
grid.style.setProperty('--grid-size', gridSize);

// render grid
grid.append(fragmentWrapper);
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(var(--grid-size) + 1), 1fr);
  /* using CSS grid size (set in JS) */
  gap: .25rem;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* align content */
  justify-content: center;
  /* align content */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  /* make cell square */
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /* show cell borders */
}

.cell.select {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
     table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      th, td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test" style="width:800px;height: 350px; border: 1px solid sandybrown;">
     
  </div>
  <script>
    var  element =  document.getElementById("test");
    var html = "<table>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        html += "<tr>";
          for (var j = 1; j<= 10; j++){
              html += "<td>"+ (i*j) +"</td>";
          }
        html += '</tr> ';
    } 
    html += "</table>";
    element.innerHTML = html;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```